# CPU Upgrade Options - rPGA Socket 989

Tags: cpu, processor-socket

I have a Samsung R730 laptop with HM55 chipset and the above socket number.

The current processor is an Intel Pentium P6100. The processor is very limited with regards to visualization etc and I would like to upgrade it.

How would I go about finding out which processors would be compatible with my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Your socket is in fact PGA988) :

http://ark.intel.com/products/50175/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6100-3M-Cache-2_00-GHz

You can only upgrade with the first or "Previous" generation of Intel® Core™ iX Processor:

http://ark.intel.com/#@MobileProducts

But be careful about if your laptop can handle so much heat. But if you can upgrade to a quad-core I7, this would be a very worthy upgrade since Intel doesn't speed up a lot its new processors

Are you sure your laptop is a Sony instead of a Samsung ?

Comment: Really? Why would CPU-Z be reporting to me that it's 989?

Comment: In fact, Intel is making a differenciation unofficially, you will find more details here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G1

Answer (score -1):

For more information, please refer to the following link regarding the upgrade project for Intel® HM55 Express Chipset.
http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/HM55_Express.html

I have an ASUS A52JK which also comes with Intel i5 430M CPU, which is shown in the link below:
https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/A52JK/

The same laptop also comes with other types of processor, which are:
1) Intel i5 430M/450M/460M/520M/540M CPU
2) Intel i3 330M/350M/370M CPU
3) Intel Pentium® Dual-Core P6000 CPU

I am thinking of upgrading the CPU of my laptop to Intel i7 940XM or i7 640M. I have checked the TDP and CPU ID for Intel i5 430M, 640M and Intel i7 940XM. The TDP for i7 940XM are higher, which is 55W while the TDP for Intel i5 430M and 640M is 35W. The CPU ID for Intel i5 430M is 20652, the CPU ID for Intel i7 540M is 20655 and the CPU ID for Intel i7 940XM is 106F1.

After reading the successful stories from the first link that I give above (and ignoring the unsuccessful stories :p ), I feel like I want to go for i7-940XM. If i7-940XM doesn't work, then I will try i7-640M (or lower). If the i7-940XM, works but have overheating problem, then I will try the i7-840QM (or lower).